# What version of Eclipse with what version of plugin Hadoop

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, for-loop, plugins

I tried various versions of Eclipse with plugins downloaded from internet but I always have problem. With latest version of eclipse and the plugin developed for Hadoop2X, I could not open the Hadoop location configuration wizard. I reinstalled eclipse with older version Ganymede. I used the plugin the one for this version, I am able to open the wizard for Hadoop location configuration but when  I try to create the project, I have given the hadoop installation direction, even then it shows the error as configure Hadoop installation directory and its not letting me move to the next section of wizard.

So can someone suggest me what version of eclipse should I use and where can I download the suitable plugin. I am using Hadoop2.5.1.

Thank You. Please help me for the same.

Comment: you have added the hadoop jar in eclipse

Comment: Yes I added the jar in eclipse dropins folder and plugins folder. But no luck